# If change in a directory then do some action in linux

Tags: database, linux

I want to store the file and file information into the database automatically, when any file is inserted into the directory.

Let suppose, in the /etc directory, we store some log files. And if we are inserted new file  into /etc directory or change any existing file then automatically these file information should be go to specific database table.

How can i do that.

Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

> INOTIFY(7)                 Linux Programmer’s Manual                INOTIFY(7)
>
> **NAME**
>
> inotify - monitoring file system events
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The inotify API provides a mechanism for monitoring file system events.
>          Inotify can be used to monitor individual files, or to monitor directo‐
>          ries.   When  a  directory is monitored, inotify will return events for
>          the directory itself, and for files inside the directory.

Inotify is Linux-specific but in addition to its C API also has (at least) binding in Python as well.  Since you don't specify what programming language you are using in Linux, I can't really help you further except recommend that you look for Inotify functions in your Linux programming environment of choice.

Comment: thanks teddy, let me know how, where I write these think? For ur information I am new in linux. So please explain in detail. And second thing, using INOTIFY(), we can monitor file system but if there is any change in file then how can insert file information into database (basically how can I call db from linux). Because I know these thing in language like java. But in linux, I don't know.

Comment: Hi teddy, for your information I am using PHP. But I can use any other language for that if PHP is not support it. So what your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).  inotify allows you to efficiently watch a directory to see when files are added or changed.

Answer (score 0):

A current-working-directory is a feature of the current shell so you can modify the `cd` command in your shell by putting:

```
function cd() {
   builtin cd $@
   do_some_action $@
}
```

in your `.bashrc` or equivalent file.

Answer (score 0):

various elementary methods

1. store the checksum of the files using `md5sum/sha512sum` command into a file/database. then check against the database everytime you run `md5sum/sha512sum`. this will check for duplicates or whether a file has changed its contents. Also compare file sizes if necessary
2. use tools like diff to compare base files
3. use  `find` or `tree` to list directory structures and store to file. remember to sort them if needed. then compare using diff for every run.
4. for other file information like modification time, access times, file permission, etc you can use `stat` command

Comment: I don't think this addresses the OP's requirement to have the file "automatically" added to the database

Answer (score 0):

[Gamin](http://people.gnome.org/~veillard/gamin/) would be another alternative. It also has Python bindings.